# Ajax - can't display posts after i submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, post, get

After i submit a post i can't display them. i don't know why aren't working. The `getPosts()` function is working when i refresh the page, everything is ok. But after i submit the posts i can't get them. I am using JSON fake server for the backend.

```
// On load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  getPosts();
});

// Sumbit post
document.querySelector('#wrapper-form').addEventListener('click', submitPost);

// Function Helpers
function submitPost(e) {
 if(e.target.dataset.role === 'submit-post') {
   http.submitPost();
   getPosts();
}

 e.preventDefault();
}

// Get posts
function getPosts() {
 http.getPosts()
   .then(response => {
     ui.populateList(response);
  })
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
 }
```

And here are the requests:

```
// Get
getPosts() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  this.xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/posts', true);

  this.xhr.onload(
   const response = JSON.parse(this.xhr.responseText);

    if(this.xhr.status === 200 && this.xhr.readyState === 4) {
     resolve(response);
    } else {
     reject('Some Error' + status);
    }
 );

  this.xhr.send();
 });
}

// Submit
submitPost() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const data = {
    title: document.querySelector(UiSelectors.titleInput).value,
    body: document.querySelector(UiSelectors.bodyInput).value
   };

  this.xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/posts', true);

  this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

  this.xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
 });
}
```

Comment: can you please explain? did you mean after submitting the post, you are not able to fetch posts?

Comment: The reason could be that your getPosts() in submit, fires before http.submitPost().
Try with promises to make sure getPosts() only fire once http.sumitPost() is done

Comment: I post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out:

```
http.submitPost()
 .then(response => {
   getPosts();
});
```

Apparently my newbie programmer skills didn't know that you can't have 2 requests at the same time. So i need it to first submit, and after i submited then get the posts.

First i did:

```
function submitPost(e) {
 if(e.target.dataset.role === 'submit-post') {
   // I did 2 requests as the same time. That was the problem
   http.submitPost();
   getPosts();
}

 e.preventDefault();
}
```